# How to test meta.valid react final form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-final-form

I am using react-final-form to validate the input field as below:

```
buildInputComponent() {
return (
  <InputField
    id="input-field"
    label="description"
    isInvalid={meta.touched && !meta.valid}
    error={meta.error}
    value=input.value
    required
    onChange={(event) => {
      input.onChange(event.target.value);
    }}
  />);
}
```

i have tested it as follows:

```
it('sets the frequency state to the value in the frequency select', () 
=>   {
       const inputValue = '30';
       testInput.find('input-field').find('input').hostNodes()
          .simulate('change', { target: { value: inputValue } });
     testInput.update();

   expect(testInput.find('ReactFinalForm').instance().state.schedule.frequency).toEqual(frequency);

  });'
```

This covers the test for meta.touched, but the coverage report shows it does not cover the test for !meta.valid
I have no idea how to cover the test for !meta.valid
I tried having empty field as below:

```
testInput.find('input-field').find('input').hostNodes()
      .simulate('change', { target: { value: frequency } });
```

But this did not cover it, Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your `touched` is always false because you are not focusing and blurring the field, ergo the latter half of the `&&` is never evaluated.

Comment: got a problem again.
I used  {meta.invalid && meta.touched} still there is no coverage for touched.
How to do that?